# CDI Extension to automatically resolve call to Remote EJB from one EAR to another EAR

Tags: java, ejb, cdi, websphere-8

I'm getting problems trying to call a remote service deployed in an EAR from another EAR.
I do not specify any names for my EJB, no matter they are @Local or @Remote and so just use annotation and inject it via @EJB.

This is what i have:

- EAR A/

  - lib/any lib jar (including API jar for remote service B)
  - war
  - ejb module(s) with service A calling remote service B
- EAR B/

  - lib/any API lib jar
  - ejb module with service B

*Additional information*: Service B implement both @Local and @Remote interfaces, and Service A inject Service B with Remote interface via:

```
@EJB private MyRemoteInterface remoteService;
```

This structure works perfectly fine with jboss server, but with websphere (8.5.5.1) one i must bind names onto my remote EJB. If do not add bindings on both EARs (i did it though admin console directly not to have to edit ejb-jar.xml) then my remote bean is not resolved at runtime.
Of course, i have to make it work with WAS, else i won't not post :)

My question: is that normal to be forced to name remote EJB with WebSphere or is it a regression (from any previous version) ? I'm expecting the injection @EJB on remote beans to works with automatic resolution on types, but maybe i'm wrong somewhere ?

**Solution**:
Because lookup must be done to make the resolution work, i decided to add the lookup configuration part onto the client ejb-jar.xml file(s). This is done automatically by maven plugin execution, with lookup name based on remote interface full name (package included) as this is the default binding WebSphere use if nothing is specified in EJB implementation.

I've chosen this solution for two reasons:

- i don't want to do the lookup in my code (duplicate code with no interest)
- i need to make it automatic and transparent for other developers

Thanks bkail for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, for business delays reason i've written a CDI extension to make the job.
The extension scan all injection point with Remote contract and proxify them. Proxies are @ApplicationScoped managed beans created on demand, and their job only consists in:

- lookup the target bean related to the scanned remote contract
- delegate the execution of the called remote method

This solution also offers me the possibility to handle lookup operation on different machine(s) by configuration though ENV variables so that deployement by container (i.e Docker) would easily works (which is one of our target in a comming future)

**EDIT**: CDI extension code below

**RemoteEjbExtension.java**:

```
public class RemoteEjbExtension implements Extension {

/**
 * This method is fired by the container for every Java EE component class
 * supporting injection that may be instantiated by the container at runtime,
 * including every managed bean declared using javax.annotation.ManagedBean,
 * EJB session or message-driven-bean, enabled bean, enabled interceptor or
 * enabled decorator.
 *
 * @param pit the event that has been fired
 */
<T> void processInjectionTarget(@Observes final ProcessInjectionTarget<T> pit) {
    for (AnnotatedField<? super T> field : pit.getAnnotatedType().getFields()) {
        if (field.getJavaMember().getType().isAnnotationPresent(Remote.class)) {
            RemoteProxyFactory.putIfAbsent(field.getJavaMember().getType());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This method is fired by the container when it has fully completed the
 * bean discovery process, validated that there are no definition errors
 * relating to the discovered beans, and registered Bean and ObserverMethod
 * objects for the discovered beans, but before detecting deployment problems.
 *
 * @param abd AfterBeanDiscovery fired events
 * @param bm Allows a portable extension to interact directly with the container.
 *          Provides operations for obtaining contextual references for beans,
 *          along with many other operations of use to portable extensions.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void afterBeanDiscovery(@Observes final AfterBeanDiscovery abd, final BeanManager bm) {

    // Roll over discovered remote interfaces
    for (final Entry<String, Class<?>> remoteClassEntry : RemoteProxyFactory.getProxyClassEntries()) {

        // Proxy that points to the remote EJB
        final Object remoteProxy;
        final Class<?> remoteClass = remoteClassEntry.getValue();

        try {
            // Build a proxy that fetches the remote EJB using JNDI
            // and delegate the call.
            remoteProxy = RemoteProxyFactory.Builder.createEJBRemoteProxy(remoteClass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Proxy creation for " + remoteClass.getCanonicalName() + " failed.", e);
        }

        final InjectionTarget<Object> it;
        try {
            AnnotatedType<Object> at = ((AnnotatedType<Object>) bm.createAnnotatedType(remoteProxy.getClass()));
            it = bm.createInjectionTarget(at);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Injection target for " + remoteClass.getCanonicalName() + " is invalid.", e);
        }

        final Bean<?> beanRemoteProxy = RemoteProxyFactory.Builder.createBeanForProxy(remoteProxy, it, remoteClass, ApplicationScoped.class);
        abd.addBean(beanRemoteProxy);
    }

}
}
```

**RemoteProxyFactory.java**:

```
public final class RemoteProxyFactory {

/** The JNDI initial context */
private static InitialContext CTX;
static {
    try {
        RemoteProxyFactory.CTX = new InitialContext();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get initial context.", e);
    }
}

private static final Map<String, Class<?>> REMOTE_EJB_CLASS_MAP = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Class<?>>();

/**
 * Register given class into proxy map
 * @param remoteEJBContractClass the remote contract's class to register
 */
public static void putIfAbsent(final Class<?> remoteEJBContractClass) {
    // Works only for same class-loader. You would change this code
    // and transform the map to handle multiple class-loader for same contract.
    // In our current configuration there is no need as APIs / IMPL libraries share the same CL.
    if (!REMOTE_EJB_CLASS_MAP.containsKey(remoteEJBContractClass.getSimpleName())) {
        REMOTE_EJB_CLASS_MAP.put(remoteEJBContractClass.getSimpleName(), remoteEJBContractClass);
    }
}

public static Set<Entry<String, Class<?>>> getProxyClassEntries() {
    return REMOTE_EJB_CLASS_MAP.entrySet();
}

public static InitialContext getContext() {
    return RemoteProxyFactory.CTX;
}

public static final class Builder {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Builder.class.getName());

    /**
     * Create a new proxy that lookup the remote EJB
     * though JNDI.
     * @param remoteEJBClazz the remote class contract
     * @return a new remote EJB proxy
     */
    public static Object createEJBRemoteProxy(final Class<?> remoteEJBClazz) {
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(remoteEJBClazz.getClassLoader(), new Class[] {
            remoteEJBClazz
        }, new InvocationHandler() {

            @Override
            public Object invoke(final Object proxy, final Method method, final Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                Object ejbInstance = null;
                try {
                    // Pull the remote EJB from the JNDI
                    ejbInstance = RemoteProxyFactory.getContext().lookup(remoteEJBClazz.getName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Remote EJB not found : " + remoteEJBClazz.getSimpleName(), e);
                }
                // Delegates the call to the remote EJB
                return method.invoke(ejbInstance, args);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create a bean for given proxy / injection target / type / scope
     * @param proxy the proxy object
     * @param it the injection target
     * @param clazz the proxy type
     * @param targetScope the returned managed bean' scope
     * @return the managed bean handling given proxy
     */
    public static <T extends Object> Bean<T> createBeanForProxy(final T proxy, final InjectionTarget<T> it, final Class<?> clazz, final Class<? extends Annotation> targetScope) {
        return new Bean<T>() {

            @Override
            public T create(final CreationalContext<T> ctx) {
                return proxy;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroy(final T instance, final CreationalContext<T> ctx) {
                it.preDestroy(instance);
                it.dispose(instance);
                ctx.release();
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getBeanClass() {
                return clazz;
            }

            @Override
            public Set<InjectionPoint> getInjectionPoints() {
                return it.getInjectionPoints();
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return clazz.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Set<Annotation> getQualifiers() {
                Set<Annotation> qualifiers = new HashSet<Annotation>();
                qualifiers.add(new AnnotationLiteral<Default>() {
                    /** Default serial-id. */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                });
                qualifiers.add(new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {
                    /** Default serial-id. */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                });
                return qualifiers;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> getScope() {
                return targetScope;
            }

            @Override
            public Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> getStereotypes() {
                return Collections.emptySet();
            }

            @Override
            public Set<Type> getTypes() {
                Set<Type> types = new HashSet<Type>();
                types.add(clazz);
                return types;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAlternative() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isNullable() {
                return false;
            }

        };
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected for WebSphere Application Server, and it is not a regression.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html) only requires automatic binding for `@EJB` when the type is within the same application:

> If no explicit linking information is provided and there is only one
>   session bean within the same application that exposes the matching
>   client view type, by default the EJB dependency resolves to that
>   session bean.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. I finally chose to automatically add lookup configuration into my "client" ejb-jar.xml file(s) (with maven plugin). In this way, i do not need to to it manually nor think to update if the remote API change.